# how to set environment variable when execle executes bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, exec, sudo

Here I tried to spawn bash using execle() and wanted to set TMOUT environment for the new bash.
It worked well. 
I could see TMOUT environment variable from the new bash shell.

```
<example1>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *env[] = {"TMOUT=60", NULL};

    execle("/bin/bash", "bash", NULL, env);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I do the same thing like example2 to use sudo, I cannot see TMOUT environment variable from the new shell.

```
<example2>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *env[] = {"TMOUT=60", NULL};

    execle("/bin/sudo", "sudo", "/bin/bash", NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to find some example like this from here.
I could find some information about example1 above.
But I could not find good information about example2.

I also tried the following using putenv().

```
<example3>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    putenv("TMOUT=60");
    execle("/bin/sudo", "sudo", "/bin/bash", NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

But this example3 also didn't work.
Can you please give me some idea how to set the environment when I use sudo like this?

Comment: Try sudo -E to preserve calling environment.

Comment: Calling environment may not have that environment variable. But the new bash shell should have the environment variable.

Comment: Use  putenv("SomeVariable=SomeValue"); before you call it.

Comment: I tried. putenv("TMOUT=60"); execle("/bin/sudo", "sudo","/bin/bash",NULL,NULL); But I cannot see TMOUT environment variable from the new bash shell. Can you tell me a little more about how I can do this?