# How to pass environment variables using execle() for /bin/login?

Tags: c, authentication, environment-variables, execl

This is similar to [how to set environment variable when execle executes bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243305/how-to-set-environment-variable-when-execle-executes-bash/55367790?noredirect=1#comment97459162_55367790)

I am trying to use execle() in C to perform /bin/login and pass the environment variable to target shell.
And can not make it work.

I have tried by passing environment as described in the man page, as a NULL terminated array of VAR=VAL strings.
Also I tried with putenv() before the call.

For example:

```
const char *env[] = { "MYVAR=myval", (char *)0 };
putenv("MYVAR=myval");
execle("/bin/login", "login", "-p", "-f", user, (char *)0, env);
```

After successful login I was expecting to see the MYVAR as an environment variable, but only have variables, like USER, HOME, SHELL, PATH etc.

I have tried with BusyBox login and with tinylogin ... same result.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `/bin/login` sets a fixed known set of environment variables and leaves it up to the shell to set others.  If you want a login shell, with Bash use `bash -l` (split up when working with `execle()`, of course); with most shells, if the last component of the path of `argv0` starts with a dash, that means 'login shell': `execle("/bin/sh", "/bin/-sh", (char *)0, env);`.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Are you sure your `execle()` is succeeding? For example, on BSD systems (including macOS) the correct path is */usr/bin/login*. You should add a `fprintf(stderr, "execle() failed with errno %d\n", errno);` after the `execle()` call.

Are you sure the BusyBox `login` command on your system supports those options?

Also, please use `NULL` rather than `(char *)0`.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan and Kurtis, thank you very much for your help and comments.

I have found out that there is no problem with env when using "-p" and when
user shell is /bin/sh.
But when I tried using "-p" and user shell was klish (CLI utility) there were
some errors in sourcing some .sh files.

So, I looked into BusyBox sources and in su.c it executes clearenv() if "-p"
is not used.

I have fixed that by passing it around and manually adding it into the env.
Since this is not the best way to do it, I will have to do some more research
about my klish sourcing.

Cheers.

Thanks again.